# how to get key in ruby on rails .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In laravel I am use to being able to access the key in a loop.  In rails I cannot find answer to how to get that from the loop.

Standard loop like so

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>

   <div class="col-md-6 subjectColumn">
       <div class="subjectBox subjectBox-<%= key %>">
           <h2><%= subject.title.capitalize %><h2> 
           <p><%= subject.description %></p>


           <a href="/subjects/<%= subject.id %>">View courses<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></h2>
       </div>

   </div>

<% end %>
```

I want to add the integer for the key in the code above.  I have tried...

```
<% @subjects.keys.each do |key, subject|
```

...and other various things I found here and elsewhere but nothing worked. The above code created an error. Most of the things I found just did not give any number.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I feel I probably just have not got the syntax quite correct or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with_index`:

```
<% @subjects.each.with_index(1) do |subject, index| %>

   <div class="col-md-6 subjectColumn">
       <div class="subjectBox subjectBox-<%= index %>">
           <h2><%= subject.title.capitalize %><h2> 
           <p><%= subject.description %></p>


           <a href="/subjects/<%= subject.id %>">View courses<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></h2>
       </div>

   </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked great, as soon as I saw that I remembered it was with_index, been awhile.  If you edit you answer so that "key" in the third line says "index" I will mark it as the answer.